# How do I supply attribute values from another XML document using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have two XML documents.  One (let's call it xml1) lists a series of 'w' elements, each with an 'orig' attribute.  The other document (xml2) lists a related series of 'w' elements, but with a different attributes ('norm').  I want to combine the two documents so that I just have the one series of  elements with all the attributes ('orig' and 'norm').

This sounds easy enough, but I can't quite get the code to work, I can't get the code to select a single value of the attribute 'norm', as opposed to all available values.

I have tried just selecting the value of the attributes from xml2 by using the command

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')//@norm"/>
```

but all this does is select the values of ALL the 'norm' attributes in xml2.

I have also tried giving each  element in the two documents a unique xml:id attribute so that they could be matched, but any time I use a conditional statement to match them, I get the same result.

If I use a 'for each' command, no  element gets selected.

Here is a sample of xml1:

```
    <text>
        <seg type="stanza" n="1">
            <l n="1">
                <w xml:id="1" orig="Haile"/>
                <w xml:id="2" orig=","/>
                <w xml:id="3" orig="sterne"/>
                <w xml:id="4" orig="superne"/>
                <w xml:id="5" orig="!"/>
            </l>
        </seg>
    </text>
```

Here is a sample of xml2:

```
    <text>
        <seg type="stanza" n="1">
            <l n="1">
                <w xml:id="1" norm="Hail"/>
                <w xml:id="2" norm=","/>
                <w xml:id="3" norm="star"/>
                <w xml:id="4" norm="supernal"/>
                <w xml:id="5" norm="!"/>
            </l>
        </seg>
    </text>
```

I would like to produce this:

```
    <text>
        <seg type="stanza" n="1">
            <l n="1">
                <w xml:id="1" orig="Haile" norm="Hail"/>
                <w xml:id="2" orig="," norm=","/>
                <w xml:id="3" orig="sterne" norm="star"/>
                <w xml:id="4" orig="superne" norm="supernal"/>
                <w xml:id="5" orig="!" norm="!"/>
            </l>
        </seg>
    </text>
```

So far, my xslt file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"    
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

    <!-- select the entirety of the document -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

    <!-- combine attributes from separate files -->
    <xsl:template match="//w">
        <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                  <xsl:attribute name="norm">
                       <xsl:value-of select="document('xml2.xml')//@norm"/>
                  </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please help me out if you can.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookups are best handled using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key)**. Try (untested):

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="norm" match="w" use="@xml:id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('norm', @xml:id, document('xml2.xml'))/@norm"/>   
    </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You don't need the key, the `id` function suffices in XSLT 2 and with `xml:id` attributes.

Comment: @MartinHonnen It doesn't seem to suffice: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfF

Comment: It seems the `xml:id` attribute values need to be valid `xs:ID` values for Saxon to support the `id` function (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWvjQfF/1), I am currently not sure whether that is intended or required by the spec or not. BaseX in XQuery seems to work fine with `id` and `xml:id="1"`, XmlPrime refuses the input XML with such ids. Not sure whether the used TEI document format really uses such numeric id values but it seems safer to go with the key if the values are numeric.

Comment: Thanks for this--this worked for me.  Thank you all for your advice and help!

Answer (score -1):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="imp" select="document('Stanza1.xml')"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="l">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="w">
                <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$imp/text/seg/l/w[@xml:id = current()/@xml:id]/@norm"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
You may use like this
```